# vector bundles on an algebraic torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is every vector bundle on an algebraic torus $T=({\mathbb A}^1\setminus \{0\})^n$
over an algebraically closed field trivial? I am primarily interested in the case of a characteristic zero base field.

Comment: Yes. See for instance Corollary V.4.10 in Lam's *Serre’s Problem on
Projective Modules*.

Comment: Yes. More generally, Gubeladze famously proved that an arbitrary vector bundle on an affine toric variety is trivial (I. Gubeladze, The Anderson conjecture and projective modules over monoid algebras, Soobshch. Akad. Nauk Gruzin. SSR 125 (1987), 289–291).